# Gazebo plugin sdf configuration tags proper documentation

Tags: gazebo-plugin, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I was documenting some Gazebo plugins and I was adding information about how to configure them (using the child sdf tags of the  element) in the doxygen plugin class documentation, but I don't know if it is the right place. I was then wondering if there is a standard/guideline for proper documenting the child sdf tags that a Gazebo plugin accepts for configuration.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4983/gazebo-plugin-sdf-configuration-tags-proper-documentation/) by [silvio.traversaro](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/455/silvio.traversaro/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 200 on 2013-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We haven't defined a standard for documenting plugins, but we should. Here is an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/952) to track this.

For now, you can put plugin documentation in the plugin's header file.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0